# Update a model and its relations with already existing primary keys

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have the following struct, with `LinguisticMetadata` being a relation:

```golang
metadataDB := &dbm.VideoMetadata{
        ID:               *imdbid,
        ImdbID:           *imdbid,
        TmdbID:           tmdbID,
        IsSeries:         input.Episode != nil,
        ImdbRating:       imdbRating,
        Adult:            extendedMetadata.Adult,

        LinguisticMetadata: linguisticListDB, // LinguisticMetadata []*LinguisticMetadata `gorm:"not null"`
        Subtitles:          subtitlesDB,      // Subtitles  []*Subtitle
    }
```

I want to create a new metadata, or update the existing one if it already exists. This is not an issue and can be achieved easily like so:

```golang
newMetadata := dbm.VideoMetadata{}
db.Where(dbm.VideoMetadata{ID: *imdbid}).Assign(metadataDB).FirstOrCreate(&newMetadata)
```

However, I also need to have the same behavior for its relations. The primary keys for `LinguisticMetadata` is the prefix of a country, eg: "en", "fr", "it"... So it is very likely that it already exists for the given metadata. Hence, if the primary keys of the relations already exist, the model should be updated (or replaced).

With the code shown above, I get the following error if the LinguisticMetadata primary key already exists:

> pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "linguistic_metadata_pkey"

This does not make sense to me, because as stated [here](http://gorm.io/docs/associations.html):

> GORM will auto save associations and its reference when creating/updating a record. **if association has a primary key, GORM will call Update to save it, otherwise it will be created.**